# Handling Threadpools & wait notifyALL()

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, queue

How to handle the thread pool where one is polling while the other should update new incoming data after processing.
The program execution beings in a controller class which has a main method and thread pool:

The main class Controller

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    RunnableController controller = new RunnableController();
    Accumulator acque = new Accumulator();
        controller.initializeDb();
        controller.initialiseThreads(acque);
        controller.initialUpdate(acque);    

}
```

The Run method for Polling class:

```
     public void run() {
    int seqId = 0;
    List<KpiMessage> list = null;
    while(true) {
        try{
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            accumulator.manageIngoing(list);            
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    }
}

  public List<KpiMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {
    Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();
    System.out.println("Polling");
 ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION = 804 and SEQ >" + 
   lastSeq + "order by SEQ DESC");  

    return pojoCol;
}
```

Run method for processing:

```
     public void run() {

    try {
        generate(accumulator.outgoingQueue);
        accumulator.manageOutgoing(accumulator.outgoingQueue, dbConnection);
         } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
```

Method for updating into Database

```
 public void updateDb(Collection<KpiMessage> updatedQueue, Connection dbConnection) throws  
  SQLException{ 
    for(KpiMessage pojoClass : updatedQueue){
            Statement stmtupd = dbConnection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Updating");
    String query = "UPDATE msg_new_to_bde SET KEYINFO1= 'Processed', KEYINFO2 = 'Updated'
   WHERE ACTION = 804"; 

           stmtupd.executeUpdate(query);**My Execution stops here**
```

Finally an accumulator class for maintaing all these queues:

```
   public boolean isUsed = false;
    public synchronized void manageIngoing(List<KpiMessage> list){

    if(this.isUsed){                
        try {
            wait(); 
            System.out.println("first wait");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("recived pass after update");
    this.getIncomingQueue().addAll(list);
     //incoming queue copied to outgoing queue
    this.setOutgoingQueue(this.getIncomingQueue());             
    System.out.println("waiting");
    System.out.println("new incoming message");
    this.isUsed = false;
    notifyAll();

}

/**
 * Method which handles synchronization using wait and notify for outgoing messages after   
  polling
 * @param outgoingQueue
 * @param dbConnection 
 */

  public synchronized void manageOutgoing(Collection<KpiMessage> outgoingQueue, Connection 
dbConnection){
    if(!this.isUsed)
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("second wait");
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    this.isUsed = true;
        DBhandler dbhandler = new DBhandler();
    try {
        dbhandler.updateDb(getOutgoingQueue(), dbConnection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    notifyAll();
}
 }
```

**My task and Question is :**

1.The controller should handle both the threads Poller & processor and accumulator handles the incoming and outgoing queues, finally fed into to updated queue for updating DB after processing

2.My class here just does polling once, is not able to update ,execution stops at

3.Is my wait(), notifyALL() handle correct here.

**How to achieve repeated polling and updation here?**

Comment: I am sorry, but you need to sumamrize or divide it into different questions separately rather than all at once

Comment: @JAtin i have updated as you have said...

Comment: @Jatin My execturtion exactly pauses at the update stament, which does nto return to looping aswell...

Answer (score 3):

Chances are, in this complex setting with five different questions, there will be no complete answer for everything. While waiting for those, you should read up on what java.util.concurrent has to offer, especially the concurrent collections with support for blocking reads and writes. Use `wait()` and `notify()` only if the JDK classes are not enough for you.

Comment: thank you, in my program it stops just printing update and the threads waits for updating ...

Comment: You can find a rather good introduction to java concurrency at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/